# Can't install package "userfriendlyscience"

Tags: r, installation, package

I need to download a package "userfriendlyscience" as it seems to be the only package which can perform a Games-Howell post-hoc test. However, when I try to install it I am unable to. I have tried 2 ways,

1. first by simply installing it and got the message:

   > Warning in install.packages :
   >   installation of package ‘userfriendlyscience’ had non-zero exit status
2. I saw online it might help to install `devtools` first (which I did) then run `devtools::install_github("matherion/userfriendlyscience", dependencies=FALSE)`. However this gave me the message:

   > ERROR: dependencies ‘data.tree’, ‘DiagrammeR’ are not available for package ‘userfriendlyscience’
   >
   > - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/userfriendlyscience’
   >     Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Thank you for any and all help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried installing dependencies

```
devtools::install_github("matherion/userfriendlyscience", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, that actually worked perfectly, thank you so much!